# Как использовать два потока в контексте одно интерпретатора Python C-API?

Tags: python, c++, c, python-3.9, python-c-api

Возможно ли использовать один главный интерпретатор Python C-API в двух разных потоках? Версия Python 3.9. Видел подобные вопросы, но сомневаюсь в актуальности их ответов. Рекомендуют после инициализации `Py_Initialize` вызвать `PyEval_InitThreads`, а затем в каждом потоке забрать и отдать GIL в начале и конце работы соответственно, но такой вариант у меня не работает, выпадает исключение `ACCESS_VIOLATION`.
Псевдокод:

```
void thr_func() {
    PyGILState_STATE gil_state;
    gil_state = PyGILState_Ensure();

    /*
    какие-то действия с Python API
    */

    PyGILState_Release(gil_state);
}

int main() {

    Py_Initialize();
    PyEval_InitThreads();

    std::thread th1(thr_func);
    std::thread th2(thr_func);
    th1.join();
    th2.join();
}
```

P.S. Я встраиваю интерпретатор в DLL-библиотеку со всеми вытекающими.